# How to ensure type safety and exhaustiveness when using objects as dictionaries?

Tags: typescript

Here is a code sample that will fail on runtime:

```
interface IDict {
  [key: string]: { id: number; name: string };
}
const something = (unknownKey: string) => {
  const aDict: IDict = {};
  const a = aDict[unknownKey];
  console.log(a.name);
};
```

What is the proper type for the dictionary so that TS forces us to always do null checks when working with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use strictNullCheck flag in compiler options. TS will start to look different on optional object. When you add `| undefined` to value definition strictNullCheck flag will force you to check is value is not undefined, or map type by `as { id: number; name: string }` syntax when you sure about returned type

```js
interface IDict {
  [key: string]: { id: number; name: string } | undefined;
}

const something = (unknownKey: string) => {
    const aDict: IDict = {};
    const a = aDict[unknownKey];
    console.log(a.name); // error
    if (a !== undefined) {
        console.log(a.name); // ok
    }
    console.log((a as { id: number; name: string }).name); //also ok
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IDict%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%20id%3A%20number%3B%20name%3A%20string%20%7D%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20something%20%3D%20(unknownKey%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20aDict%3A%20IDict%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20a%20%3D%20aDict%5BunknownKey%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(a.name)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(a%20!%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(a.name)%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log((a%20as%20%7B%20id%3A%20number%3B%20name%3A%20string%20%7D).name)%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B)

Comment: I actually do have strict null check turned on, but the actual solution was adding `| undefined` to the value definition, thanks

Comment: Glad to help :). Could you approve my answer to be more visible for others?